# Second parameter sent to Angular filter undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am trying to implement a search with a custom filter and it seems that the second parameter sent to filter is undefined. Objects searched are books, with genre array attribute within.

For searching purposes I have an array of genre objects which are set via controller in a multiple select element.

Issue is that the second parameter sent to the custom filter is undefined. Following is the filter code inside the controller. I've debugged the code and filter logic is ok, except that it throws that the filterBy is undefined:

CONTROLLER -

```
app.filter('genres', function () {
    return function (books, filterBy) {
        console.log(filterBy);
        return books.filter(function (element, index, array) {
            return element.genre === filterBy.genre;
        });
    };
});
```

HTML-

```
<div ng-controller="LibraryController as libraryCtrl">
    <form>
        Book name
        <input type="text" name="Book name" ng-model="filterBy.name" class="inputTxtForm">
        <br/> Author
        <input type="text" name="author" ng-model="filterBy.rating" class="inputTxtForm">
        <br/> Genres
        <select multiple="true" ng-model="filterBy.genre" ng-options="genre for genre in libraryCtrl.genres" class="inputTxtForm">
        </select>
    </form>
    <section class="tableSection">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="book in libraryCtrl.books | filter:filterBy | genres:filterBy">
                <td>
                    {{book.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{book.author}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{book.genre.join()}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you initializing finterBy to anything in your controller? Is it still undefined after you enter something into one of the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change filterBy to libraryCtrl.filterBy

```
<div ng-controller="LibraryController as libraryCtrl">
<form>
    Book name
    <input type="text" name="Book name" ng-model="libraryCtrl.filterBy.name" class="inputTxtForm">
    <br/> Author
    <input type="text" name="author" ng-model="libraryCtrl.filterBy.rating" class="inputTxtForm">
    <br/> Genres
    <select multiple="true" ng-model="libraryCtrl.filterBy.genre" ng-options="genre for genre in libraryCtrl.genres" class="inputTxtForm">
    </select>
</form>
<section class="tableSection">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="book in libraryCtrl.books | filter:libraryCtrl.filterBy | genres:libraryCtrl.filterBy">
            <td>
                {{book.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{book.author}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{book.genre.join()}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

Here's the sample [link]
http://plnkr.co/edit/FtWDzTvxROECsOs0zTQ7?p=preview

Check console log for filterby values